# Importing file xls with large data/record using jquery-ajax-php so the browser wont timeout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to import xls data, with about 1500 rows data. which if using standard timeout execution time it will be timeout.

i want to use jQuery ajax, but i dunt know how to do it, so the process wont timeout. my current ajax script:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            importXLS();
        });
    });

    function importXLS()
    {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "the_url",
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                if(result.count>0) {                                                                
                    $('#result').append(result.html);                        
                } else {
                    var alert = $('<div class="alert alert-success">'+ result.message +'</div>');
                    $("#report").before(alert);
                    $(".alert").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        alert.remove();
                    });
                }

                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "timeout"?

Comment: timeout, like when we loading too long, the request is cancelled, which can be set on php.ini, but i dont want to set the limit_execution_time on php.ini

Comment: Not sure if jQuery sets an internal timeout which aborts request  by default at `$.ajax()` call. Have you tried using `XMLHttpRequest()`?

Comment: There is a call to `setTimeout` at `jQuery.ajax()` source `// Timeout
        if (s.async && s.timeout > 0) {
            timeoutTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                jqXHR.abort("timeout");
            },
            s.timeout);
        }`